# Trying to split an int array into 2 and check if their averages can be equal using a recursive approach

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, dynamic-programming

My code

```
    public boolean canSplitArraySameAverage(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {

        double aSum = 0, bSum = 0;

        for (int it : a)   // aSum
            aSum = aSum + it;


        for (int it : b)   // bSum
            bSum = bSum + it;


        if ((!a.isEmpty() && !b.isEmpty()) && (bSum / b.size() == aSum / a.size())) //  Equal Average Possible
            return true;


        if (b.size() == 1)  //  Solution not possible, returning on reaching base case
            return false;


        for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) { 

            a.add(b.remove(i));  // Transferring element from b to a

            // Creating Deep Copies
            ArrayList<Integer> newA = (ArrayList<Integer>) a.clone();
            ArrayList<Integer> newB = (ArrayList<Integer>) b.clone();

            if (canSplitArraySameAverage(newA, newB))
                return true;  // Early true return

        }

        System.out.println("Return :" + a);  
        return false;  //  Solution not possible, returning after exhausting for loop
    }
```

[Logical Flow on how the code should execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFR8S.png)

Passing values a[] and b[1 2 3 4]

When reaching a negative base case(b[] size = 1) I expect the value of a[] to be as follows

```
[1 2 3]
[1 2 4]
[1 2]
[1 3 2]
[1 3 4]
[1 3]
and so on
```

However my code executes as

```
[1 2 3]
[1 2 4]
[1 3 2]
[1 3]
and terminates
```

I am not sure where the problem is, I suspect it to be with the return statements.

Comment: Do you really need the for loop? Can't you just use the recursion to handle it? Try removing the loop the and just do one transfer if the length of b is > 1 and call the method again.

Comment: @nordenvall, I believe that the for loop is needed so that the branching happens properly, I could be wrong however.
I did try removing the for loop and placing the updating code within it but then it executes just the left most branch. 

The output became
[1 2 3] 
[1 2] 
[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before cloning the ArrayLists, you are adding the value from the original List `b` to the original List `a`.

This means when doing the first call of your recursive method, the first element of the original List `b` (in your case: 1) will always be the first element of `newA`.

The solution to this is to transfer the element after doing the copy:

```java
      // Creating Deep Copies
      ArrayList<Integer> newA = (ArrayList<Integer>) a.clone();
      ArrayList<Integer> newB = (ArrayList<Integer>) b.clone();

      newA.add(newB.remove(i));
```

Note: Due to your early true return, not all invalid cases are visited

---

**Edit: More explanation**

Assuming you make execute your method (from the question). This will not visit all possible combinations and deliver a wrong result.

The reason, why not all combinations are examined is, because you are transfering elements from `b` to `a` before making a copy.

Lets take a look at what happens in the for-loop:

- The for loop is entered with `i == 0`
- element is transfered from (original) `b` to `a`
- now a = [1], b = [2,3,4]
- the recursion part happens
- i is increased. now `i == 1`
- because you removed the first element from the original `b`, the next element that will be added is 3 (because `i == 1`)
- this leads to that, that in a further step the combination of [1,4] [2,3] is never examined, and your method delivers a wrong result.

---

Here is the fixed code of your method:

```java
public static boolean canSplitArraySameAverage(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {

  double aSum = a.stream().reduce(0, (x,y) -> x+y);
  double bSum = b.stream().reduce(0, (x,y) -> x+y);
  
  if ((!a.isEmpty() && !b.isEmpty()) && (bSum / b.size() == aSum / a.size())) //  Equal Average Possible
    return true;
  
  if (b.size() == 1) //  Solution not possible, returning on reaching base case
    return false;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
    // Creating Deep Copies
    ArrayList<Integer> newA = (ArrayList<Integer>) a.clone();
    ArrayList<Integer> newB = (ArrayList<Integer>) b.clone();
  
    // Transferring element from newB to newA
    newA.add(newB.remove(i));
  
    if (canSplitArraySameAverage(newA, newB))
      return true;  // Early true retur
  }
  
  System.out.println("Return :" + a);
  return false;  //  Solution not possible, returning after exhausting for loop
}
```

When executing this method with two lists `a` and `b`, where a is empty and `b` contains `[1,2,3,4]`, the output is:

```
Return :[1, 2]
Return :[1, 3]
```

and the result of the method is 'true', because splitting into [1,4] and [2,3] delivers the same average. 
There is not more output, because when the size of `b` is 1, then only false is returned, without making an output.

The combinations checked in the different recursion levels are:

```
Recursion-Level: 0; a = [], b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Recursion-Level: 1; a = [1], b = [2, 3, 4]
Recursion-Level: 2; a = [1, 2], b = [3, 4]
Recursion-Level: 3; a = [1, 2, 3], b = [4]
Recursion-Level: 3; a = [1, 2, 4], b = [3]
Recursion-Level: 2; a = [1, 3], b = [2, 4]
Recursion-Level: 3; a = [1, 3, 2], b = [4]
Recursion-Level: 3; a = [1, 3, 4], b = [2]
Recursion-Level: 2; a = [1, 4], b = [2, 3]
```

Comment: In the original call, I am passing       [  ] and [1 2 3 4] 
In the second call it becomes           [1] and [2 3 4]
Then                                               [1 2] and [3 4]

And so on, so the value of newA gets updated in each call

If I were to print the values in 'b' before updating and 'a' after updating, I get the following values
```
B :[1 2 3 4]
A :[1]
B :[2 3 4]
A :[1 2]
B :[3 4]
A :[1 2 3]

B :[3 4]
A :[1 2 4]

B :[2 3 4]
A :[1 3]
B :[2 4]
A :[1 3 2]
```

I also tried your suggestion, it gave me
[1 2 3 4]
[1 2 3]
[1 3] 
Not sure what to make of it

Comment: @codingcredo
Updated my answer with some detailed explanation why transfering the element after cloning the list is important. If you need to print more combinations that are examined, you need to add an output to the first "return false;" in your method.
If you need to print all combinations, you need to overthink your early-exit strategy.

Comment: thank you so much! Initially I misunderstood your solution and I ended up transferring the element twice instead of repositioning the line.
And I am also really grateful for the detailed explanation it has helped me understand where I was going wrong and how you corrected it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print all the not possible values of a you can't return from the for-loop, the you will break out of it on the first positive combination.

This works for me (sorry rewrote it in C# since I don't have java IDE available atm but I think you grasp the changes):

```
private bool CanSplitArraySameAverage(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        
        double aSum = 0, bSum = 0;

        foreach (var it in a)
        {
            aSum = aSum + it;
        }

        foreach (int it in b)
        {
            bSum = bSum + it;
        }

        if ((a.Any() && b.Any()) && (bSum / b.Count() == aSum / a.Count()))
        {
            return true;
        }

        bool canSplit = false;
        if(b.Count() != 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Count(); i++)
            {
                List<int> newA = new List<int>(a);
                List<int> newB = new List<int>(b);

                newA.Add(newB.ElementAt(i));  
                newB.RemoveAt(i);

                if (this.CanSplitArraySameAverage(newA, newB))
                {
                    canSplit = true;
                }

            }
        }

        if (!canSplit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Return :" + String.Join("-", a));
        }
        return canSplit;  
    }
```

Gives the output:

```
Return :1-2-3
Return :1-2-4
Return :1-2
Return :1-3-2
Return :1-3-4
Return :1-3
Return :2-1-3
Return :2-1-4
Return :2-1
Return :2-4-1
Return :2-4-3
Return :2-4
Return :3-1-2
Return :3-1-4
Return :3-1
Return :3-4-1
Return :3-4-2
Return :3-4
Return :4-2-1
Return :4-2-3
Return :4-2
Return :4-3-1
Return :4-3-2
Return :4-3
```

No combinations of 2-3 or 1-4

Comment: Thanks a lot @nordenvall, this was helpful and yes I was able to follow along with the changes, thank you!